# Problem when processing from CSV to CSV with a row count

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to process a CSV file into a new CSV file with only columns of interest and remove rows with unfit values of -1. Unfortunately I get unexpected results, as it automatically includes column 0 (old ID) into the new CSV file without explicitly asking the script to do it (as it is not defined in cols = [..]).

How could I change these values for the new row count. That for, when for example we remove row 9 with an id=9, the dataset id goes currently as [..7,8,10...] instead of a new id count as [..7,8,9,10...]. I hope anyone got a solution for it.

```
import pandas as pd

# take only specific columns from dataset
cols = [1, 5, 6]
data = pd.read_csv('data_sample.csv', usecols=cols, header=None) data.columns = ["url", "gender", "age"]

# remove rows from dataset with undefined values of -1
data = data[data['gender'] != -1]  
data = data[data['age'] != -1]

""" Additional working solution 
indexGender = data[data['gender'] == -1].index 
indexAge = data[data['age'] == -1].index

# Delete the rows indexes from dataFrame 
data.drop(indexGender,inplace=True) 
data.drop(indexAge, inplace=True)
"""
data.to_csv('data_test.csv')
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem via simple line after the data drop:

```
data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```